# Adding a class to a symbol makes the symbol appear in the next line

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I add an class to this symbol (▼) the symbol jumps to the next line:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpuPA.jpg

the code, its a dropdown button with the text "JS Array" and next to it I want the symbol.

```
<a href="#content-array-intro" class="nav-link dropdown-btn">JS Array 
<div class="test">&#x25BC;</div></a>
```

Without a class it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkLRi.jpg

the code, now without a class.

```
<a href="#content-array-intro" class="nav-link dropdown-btn">JS Array 
&#x25BC;</a>
```

the css:

```
.nav-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
}
```

And I want it to look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvPQE.jpg
I want the symbol to be at the end, and I know I can do it if I can add a class to this symbol.

If you have a solution on how I can fix that without adding a class, that would be even better.

Comment: And what does your css look like? In particular, is there a width on the `.nav-link`? Is there a `display:block;` on `.test`? Without the CSS, we can't do much.

Comment: I added the CSS if some other people need it in the future. I had no css for the .test. But the answer from @IceMetalPunk already worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the class that's the problem, it's the div. Div elements are by default block displayed, meaning they won't stay inline with text. To get the behavior you want, use an inline element instead (such as a span), or set the class to have `display: inline` to force the div to act like an inline element instead of a block element.

Comment: Yes that worked, I wrapped the symbol in a span and added a class to the span, and to the css class i just added, `float:left`, and `margin-right: 10px;`, thank you very much!